# issue in writing sql query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
Table :
ID | ID1 | ID2
 A |     |  
 B |  A  |
 C |     |
 D |  B  |  C
 E |     |


Expected Output :
ID | ID1 | ID2 
 D |  B  |  C
 E |     |
```

Hi, 
We have use-case where we need to filter out all the rows where ID matches with ID1, ID2 of any row in table
Can someone guide how can I do this in redshift SQL ??

Comment: Closed because it needs details or clarity! What is not clear in: *filter out all the rows where ID matches with ID1, ID2 of any row in table*?

Comment: @forpas Can you suggest some optimization on this query as our data size is too large ?

Comment: This is a very simple design. I guess ID is already indexed. So you can try indexes on id1 and id2 and/or maybe a composite index of id1 and id2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where t.id in (id1, id2)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5NCQzhK1ZSNj34bHLgET4v/1).

Or with a `LEFT` self join from which the matched rows are filtered out:

```
select t1.* 
from tablename t1 left join tablename t2
on t1.id in (t2.id1, t2.id2)
where t2.id1 is null and t2.id2 is null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5NCQzhK1ZSNj34bHLgET4v/3).

Results:

```
| ID  | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D   | B   | C   |
| E   |     |     |
```